# Acessar lista de dentro de um ViewHolder em Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Preciso acessar uma lista que está no Adapter, porém, preciso acessar estando em um ViewHolder, sei que com Java bastaria referenciar a lista, porém, em Kotlin a lista não é reconhecida, porque?

```
class SearchFilterAdapter(private val filterList: List<Filter>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchFilterAdapter.ViewHolder>(), FastScrollRecyclerView.SectionedAdapter {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_search_filter, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return filterList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(filterList[position])
    }

    override fun getSectionName(position: Int): String {
        return filterList[position].group?.toUpperCase()!!
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val sectionTextView = itemView?.sectionTextView
        val filterCheckBox = itemView?.filterCheckBox
        val rootLayout = itemView?.rootLayout

        fun bind(filter: Filter) {

            if(filter.isFirst) {
                sectionTextView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                sectionTextView?.text = filter.group?.toUpperCase()
            } else {
                sectionTextView?.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            filterCheckBox?.isChecked = filter.isChecked

            filterCheckBox?.setOnCheckedChangeListener {
                buttonView, isChecked ->
                //filterList[position].isChecked = isChecked
            }

            filterCheckBox?.text = filter.category
        }
    }
}
```

Note que há um comentário, é lá que tentei acessar a lista que está no adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Kotlin, uma *nested class*, por padrão, não pode acessar os membros da classe de fora.

Para conseguir isso, use o modificador `inner` na declaração da *nested class*:

```
class SearchFilterAdapter(private val filterList: List<Filter>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchFilterAdapter.ViewHolder>(), FastScrollRecyclerView.SectionedAdapter {

    ...

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Você pode ler mais detalhes na [documentação de nested e inner classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html).